# how to search and change dates. in r using datatable

Tags: r, date, datatable

this just head() from my dataset, there are millions of rows. this is how it looks

```
#before
dt$date[c("2010-05-12" "2010-05-28" "2010-06-29" "2010-06-30" "2010-07-02" "2010-07-02")]
```

i want to convert these to the last day of the month.
but i have to accommodate the fact that months end in 30 and 31. how would i change accordingly?

```
#after 
[c("2010-05-31" "2010-05-31" "2010-06-30" "2010-06-30" "2010-07-31" "2010-07-31")]
```

Cheers

Comment: Would it be suitable to remove the date? `format(dt$date, format = "%Y-%m")` Or do you really need the last date of each month?

Comment: hi @DanielO, unfortunately i need the last dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `lubridate` package

```
require(lubridate)
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2010-05-12", "2010-05-28", "2010-06-29", "2010-06-30", "2010-07-02", "2010-07-02")))

day(dt$date) <- days_in_month(dt$date)
```

output:

```
> dt 
         date
1: 2010-05-31
2: 2010-05-31
3: 2010-06-30
4: 2010-06-30
5: 2010-07-31
6: 2010-07-31
```

Comment: Also with `lubridate` you could do `ceiling_date(dt$date, "month") - 1` to get the last date of the month.

Comment: for some reason my column is type 'character' ,so it wont work.  i tried to convert using `as.Date(dt$date, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"))` but it doesn't work. how could i tackle the conversion.

Comment: it works with the example dates you have shown above. Perhaps there is an entry somewhere in the list that has a different format? you could check with `any(!grepl("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}",dt$date))`, If you receive a `TRUE` then at least one date is different.

Comment: @Ben i tried using `ceiling date` in my dataset but was still getting days of months returning '26/25'  as ceiling date rounds to nearest value. how could i bypass this?

Comment: @Tykid15 It sounds like you may have problems with dates in different formats, as described in the comments above. Did you look into that further or try @Daniel O's code to check? Otherwise, you are welcome to provide an example where the above code (with or without `ceiling_date`) does not work to better understand your problem. But again, it may be worthwhile to focus on just converting your dates into `Date` objects first. There are a number of other SO questions/answers on this topic, including with `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 0):

Base solution (works on data.table objects) with several steps.

```
# Find the range: date_range => Date vector
date_range <- range(df$date)

# Generate a sequence, having every date in the range: 
# date_lkp => Date vector
date_lkp <- seq.Date(date_range[1], date_range[2], by = "days")

# Truncate the date to months: mth_date => Date Vector
mth_date <- as.Date(paste0(substr(date_lkp, 1, 8), "01"), "%Y-%m-%d")

# Store every date in the sequence as well as the date for each 
# end of month: date_tab => data.frame
date_tab <- data.frame(date_lkp = date_lkp, 
                       eom_date = ave(date_lkp, mth_date, FUN = max))

# Perform a lookup for each date in the original data to retrieve 
# the last day of each month: new_date =>  Date vector
df$eom_date <- date_tab$eom_date[match(df$date, date_tab$date_lkp)]

# Data: 
date <- c("2010-05-12",
          "2010-05-28",
          "2010-06-29",
          "2010-06-30",
          "2010-07-02",
          "2010-07-02")
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(date = date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```